# JavaScript programming logic with JSON

Tags: javascript, json, logic

I have a JSON object as below:

```
{"_id":"594fe31b3e158c0e70c9bb3e","deviceid":"342","alldata":"{\"deviceid\":\"342\",\"voltage\":\"14\",\"current\":\"9\",\"power\":\"92\",\"status\":\"1\"}","receivedon":"2017/06/25 21:51:47","__v":0}
```

The issue is that, when I try to output `obj.alldata.voltage`, it just gives blank; which leads me to think that `obj.alldata` is a string and not a JSON object.

When I print `obj.alldata`, it gives an output like:

```
{"deviceid":"342","voltage":"14","current":"9","power":"92","status":"1"}
```

How can I use `obj.receivedon`, as well as `obj.alldata.voltage`, correctly?

Comment: try [jsonifing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) obj.alldata

Comment: You should use the parse() function in JS, and the data becomes a JavaScript object.

Comment: "which leads me to think that obj.alldata is a string and not a JSON object" exactly. There is no such thing as a JSON object. You have to understand with what types you are dealing. You either have an object, or a string *(wich may or may not contain JSON)*. And you can only access the properties on the object, not on the string.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotes of the `alldata` value, so it won't be treated as string.

```
{ "_id": "594fe31b3e158c0e70c9bb3e", "deviceid": "342", "alldata": { "deviceid":"342","voltage":"14","current":"9","power":"92","status":"1"}, "receivedon": "2017/ 06 / 25 21: 51:47", "__v": 0 };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = {
        "_id": "594fe31b3e158c0e70c9bb3e",
        "deviceid": "342",
        "alldata": {\"deviceid\":\"342\",\"voltage\":\"14\",\"current\":\"9\",\"power\":\"92\",\"status\":\"1\"}",
        "receivedon": "2017/06/25 21:51:47",
        "__v": 0
       }
```

The above is a hash or a js object except the value for key "alldata" is a json, you need to parse that json

data.alldata = JSON.parse(data.alldata)

After this your object will look like this

```
     { _id: "594fe31b3e158c0e70c9bb3e", 
       deviceid: "342", : 
       alldata: {
          deviceid: "342",
          voltage: "14",
          current: "9",
          power: "92",
          status: "1"
      }, 
     receivedon: "2017/06/25 21:51:47", __v: 0
    }
```